# Поиск по столбцу в excel

Tags: excel

Есть столбец, нужно вернуть номер клетки в этом столбце, содержимое которой соответствует значению "банк"

Answer (score 0):

```
=ПОИСКПОЗ("банк";A1:A100;)
```